# Lua | String Patterns | Pattern to find strings within a string

Tags: string, lua

I am making an in-game script editor, and its almost complete. Aside from needing to script in key-binds and such, I need to fix some problems with the Syntax Highlighter.
Here is how the editor looks so far: 
 (UI has had no work done to it, ignore it.)

[image: Picture of editor in game]

As you can clearly see, there are some bugs to work out, such as some parenthesis refusing to highlight. The bigger problem resides in my pattern for findings strings though:

`(([^\\]*["\']).*%2)`

This pattern causes this: 
[image: Items between two strings become highlighted]

I took a break from working on this a few weeks ago, and I don't really remember as well on how patterns work. I have tried modifying my existing pattern to prevent text between strings from being included with match, but it either selects EVERYTHING, or doesn't find any strings.
I need to make sure it doesn't find \' or \" to be an indicator for a string either.

Comment: Please provide more details, are you looking for a regex match?

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is a bit complicated. You can simply match balanced pairs of `"` using the pattern `%b""`

```
local myString = 'local a = {"one", "two", "tree"}'

for str in myString:gmatch('%b""') do print(str) end
```

prints

```
"one"
"two"
"tree"
```

See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1

> **%bxy**, where x and y are two distinct characters; such item matches
>   strings that start with x, end with y, and where the x and y are
>   balanced. This means that, if one reads the string from left to right,
>   counting +1 for an x and -1 for a y, the ending y is the first y where
>   the count reaches 0. For instance, the item %b() matches expressions
>   with balanced parentheses.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  The OP says: I need to make sure it doesn't find \' or \" to be an indicator for a string either.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using a `greedy` match. This will purposely find the longest matching string. Instead you should use a `lazy`  match. This will allow you to match just the first string. Lazy matches use the `-` symbol instead of the `+`

So now you can write simple pattern for each variant of the string

```
> print(([["foo"]]):match("\"[^\"]-\""))
"foo"
> print(([["foo"  "bar"]]):match("\"[^\"]-\""))
"foo"
>
```